# Google Speech API doesn't give correct result when audio is sent in file

Tags: perl, audio, ffmpeg, google-apps

I chanced upon the article at [Google Speech API](http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/comment-page-3/#comment-2527) which suggested a mechanism for extracting text from audio file through Perl. Now I have recorded a audio file, which you will find at http://vocaroo.com/i/s0lPN5d3YQJj. It is a simple piece of audio, reading **I love you**. When I go to the Google speech API in Chrome, and speak those words, I get the right result. When I try the code at the above mentioned link with the audio file I pointed out, it returns strange results, like **logan**. How can I make it more accurate? This is just a sample audio, what I am generally doing is extracting the audio from a video file through FFMpeg using something like `ffmpeg -i input.avi -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3 output.mp3`, followed by `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.flac`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried playing the audio files you are creating?

You are setting an audio bitrate of 192 bits/second which is ridiculously low.

For 192Kbps you need `-ab 196608`.

Comment: `-ab 196608` or `-ar 196608`?

Comment: You heard the audio, right? It sounds quite decent, why shouldn't the API pick that up?

Comment: You want `-ab 196608`. `-ar` is the sample rate which is fine at 44.1KHz. And if it is the FLAC file you have posted then my guess is that Google is struggling with your eastern accent

Comment: Ok, will try it and let you know.

Comment: @Cupidvogel FFmpeg also accepts units in numbers so instead of `-ab 196608` you can just write `-ab 192k`